# Unable to find option to delete ibm cloud resource groups

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is there a way to delete the IBM Cloud IAM (Identity and Access Management) Resource Groups? As for as I have seen the documentation and searched, there is no option to delete but to rename and assign the resources. Why there is no option to delete the resource groups?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the "why", but right now it is a documented limitation. [See this question and answer on deleting resource groups in the IBM Cloud documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/resources/faqs.html#delete-resource-group).

Comment: @data_henric, yes I saw the documented limitation but do not know the specific reason for that limitation. Hence that question. Anyway, for now looks like need to wait for some update on this.